# What happens when SELECT ... FOR UPDATE returns multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I'm working on some dead-lock troubleshooting, particularly involving a row-swap.

Currently the statements look like this, all running under the same transaction:

```
SELECT IDENTIFIER FROM tables WHERE (TABLEID = 4 OR TABLEID = 5) AND DATE = "2015-10-31" FOR UPDATE; 
/* Would imagine this would lock both of these rows.*/

UPDATE tables SET LINK=0 WHERE DATE = "2015-10-31" AND LINK = 5;

UPDATE tables SET TABLEID = -1 WHERE TABLEID = 5 AND DATE = "2015-10-31";

UPDATE tables SET TABLEID = 5 WHERE TABLEID = 4 AND DATE = "2015-10-31";

/* Deadlock on 2nd connection occurs here */
UPDATE tables SET TABLEID = 4 WHERE TABLEID = -1 AND DATE = "2015-10-31";

COMMIT; 
/* Would imagine this would release locks and let the next transaction continue */
```

If I run two of these transactions at the same time (run query 1 in connection ONE, query 1 in connection TWO, then proceed with 2-3-4-5 in connection ONE) I get a deadlock every time on connection TWO.

Why? Should the first query not lock BOTH rows returned (in this case there are *always* two) and then not let the later transaction perform any SELECTS for these two rows until the first transaction has `COMMIT`'ed

Bear in mind the table name is `tables` in this case, just to avoid any confusion.

Indexes look like:

```
IDENTIFIER (primary, AI integer)
LINK (regular index)
DATE (regular index)
TABLEID+DATE (unique composite, in that order)
```

I can circumvent the issue by locking the entire table (`LOCK TABLES tables WRITE`, `UNLOCK TABLES`), but I'm trying to avoid an entire table lock.

MySQL 5.6.23, default isolation level (repeatable read)

In response to answer: If FOR UPDATE does not prevent other FOR UPDATEs to lock the same row, how come this happens:

```
Connection 1: SELECT IDENTIFIER FROM tables WHERE (TABLEID = 4 OR TABLEID = 5) AND DATE = "2015-10-31" FOR UPDATE; 

/* THIS WILL WAIT */
Connection 2: SELECT IDENTIFIER FROM tables WHERE (TABLEID = 4 OR TABLEID = 5) AND DATE = "2015-10-31" FOR UPDATE; 

Connection 1: COMMIT;

Connection 2 (statement runs): COMMIT;
```

No errors. Both statements returned both rows, but the second one **waited for the first to commit**. This makes my problem seem irrational. If the FOR UPDATE does indeed wait for the commit, why do I get a deadlock error at all?
MySQL Documentation says:

"A kind of lock that prevents any other transaction from locking the same row" about X-locks, which FOR UPDATE is. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_exclusive_lock

Edit: LATEST DEADLOCK is

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2015-10-26 18:39:47 2b308cbde700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 12590262, ACTIVE 19 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 199074, OS thread handle 0x2b308cc1f700, query id 5754285 172.31.39.158 awsroot Sending data
SELECT IDENTIFIER,NAME,STATUS,PRICE,GUESTS,EMAIL,NOTE,BOOKER,EDITOR,SELLER,TABLEID,LINK,LASTCLIENT FROM tables WHERE (TABLEID = 4 OR TABLEID = 5) AND DATE = "2015-10-31" 
LIMIT 0, 1000
FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2660 page no 4 n bits 232 index `table_ident` of table `apple`.`tables` trx id 12590262 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 157 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 8004; asc   ;;
 1: len 3; hex 8fbf5f; asc   _;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000004; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 12590261, ACTIVE 22 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
9 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 13 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 199078, OS thread handle 0x2b308cbde700, query id 5754318 172.31.39.158 awsroot updating
UPDATE tables SET TABLEID = 4 WHERE TABLEID = -1 AND DATE = "2015-10-31"
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 2660 page no 4 n bits 232 index `table_ident` of table `apple`.`tables` trx id 12590261 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 42 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 8005; asc   ;;
 1: len 3; hex 8fbf5f; asc   _;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 157 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 8004; asc   ;;
 1: len 3; hex 8fbf5f; asc   _;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000004; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 158 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 7fff; asc   ;;
 1: len 3; hex 8fbf5f; asc   _;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2660 page no 4 n bits 232 index `table_ident` of table `apple`.`tables` trx id 12590261 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 157 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 8004; asc   ;;
 1: len 3; hex 8fbf5f; asc   _;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000004; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

`table_ident` is the TABLEID+DATE unique index.

SHOW CREATE TABLE for `tables`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tables` (
  `IDENTIFIER` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TABLEID` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRICE` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `GUESTS` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `STATUS` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `NOTE` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LINK` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SELLER` mediumint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `EDITOR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER` mediumint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LASTEDIT` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `BOOKER` mediumint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LASTCLIENT` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDENTIFIER`),
  UNIQUE KEY `table_ident` (`TABLEID`,`DATE`),
  KEY `DATE` (`DATE`),
  KEY `SELLER` (`SELLER`),
  KEY `LINK` (`LINK`),
  KEY `BOOKER` (`BOOKER`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER` (`CUSTOMER`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `tables_booker` FOREIGN KEY (`BOOKER`) REFERENCES `people` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `tables_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER`) REFERENCES `people` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `tables_link` FOREIGN KEY (`LINK`) REFERENCES `layout` (`TABLEID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tables_seller` FOREIGN KEY (`SELLER`) REFERENCES `people` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `tables_tableid` FOREIGN KEY (`TABLEID`) REFERENCES `layout` (`TABLEID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=316 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Use `show engine innodb status;` at different steps to see some locks and waits on your transaction, then check it after the deadlock to see info about it. The row-level locks are actually "index-item" locks and there are multiple types. My first guess is that the first query in the second connection manages to get hold on some shared lock which conflicts with the needs of the 5th query - so noone can continue and one has to be killed - and the transaction #2 holds less locks so is a good victim for the deadlock resolution. I can't test this right now but will try tomorrow,

Comment: I was able to get a deadlock even sooner when ignoring the index on `DATE` on one or both selects, but my testing table has exactly rows only (and I use MariaDB 10 but that should usually not matter in this case). Probably the wrong index is used because I do not have the same data in the table.. Can you pastebin `show create table tables` and some inserts to share a testcase you use?

Comment: The inserts you see above are the statements I actually use. I can give you the create table but the table itself has a lot more columns. The ones that are indexed are listed above. I'm considering remodeling this transaction so it selects on the IDENTIFIER column only, (primary) instead of TABLEID+DATE. I think that would resolve the issue entirely. I have updated the question with LAST DEADLOCK from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS.

Comment: I cannot see any INSERT statements in you question. I thought you already simplified it to a small "testcase".

Comment: You can insert whatever you want, as long as you have two TABLEID rows that you can swap around (like 4 and 5 in my example). I ran my testcase on the actual table, I just removed all the columns that are not relevant to anything (name, email, whatever). And just remove the contraints to the other tables. They are not relevant either.

Comment: Check the [deadlock example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-lock-modes.html#idm140440089165984) in manual - reading the `LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK`: the first transaction tries to put an S lock (maybe of a different type than the X lock it is already holding - it has no `rec but not gap`) on one of the rows the second transaction is waiting for with X lock request - so it deadlocks.

Comment: What is the explain for the first query? Does the plan change if you change the predicate to `WHERE TABLEID BETWEEN 4 AND 5`

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:  Change

```
UNIQUE KEY `table_ident` (`TABLEID`,`DATE`),
KEY `DATE` (`DATE`),
```

to

```
UNIQUE KEY `table_ident` (`DATE`,`TABLEID`), -- swapped to assist with `SELECT`
KEY `DATE` (`TABLEID`),   -- in case you need it
```

Comment: What difference would this make? I get the same sum of indexes and the same advantages for select?

Comment: For `WHERE (TABLEID = 4 OR TABLEID = 5) AND DATE = "2015-10-31"` it is slightly better to have the date first.

Answer (score 0):

Single-step swap:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE tables
    SET TABLEID = 4+5 - TABLEID
    WHERE TABLEID IN (4, 5)
      AND DATE = "2015-10-31";
COMMIT;
```

This might help avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Never seen this procedure before. For now I just use LOCK TABLES to prevent these deadlocks. I was under the impression that single step swap was impossible in MySQL.

Comment: It is a simple pattern:  To swap two things, subtract from the sum.  Do not use `LOCK TABLES` with InnoDB.

Comment: Clever. I will try it. Unfortunately I need values from SELECT from each row prior to performing the swap. According to the manual LOCK TABLES is fine to use with InnoDB - it gives less concurrency but uses less RAM and prevents deadlocks. Why should I not use it?

Comment: Hmmm...  You need `IDENTIFIER` for something after the `COMMIT`?

Comment: I need the status and last edit timestamp of each row. Also I cannot do the single statement swap because of unique constraints.

Comment: Hmmmm...  `LOCK TABLES` will block all activity on the table.  You are risking delays, if not deadlocks.  Deadlocks are not evil; they just need to be dealt with.  The usual 'cure' is to rerun the `BEGIN...COMMIT`.

Comment: The table is not busy enough to be delayed by a table lock. I think I can think of a way to do SELECT WHERE IDENTIFIER instead of (TABLEID OR TABLEID) AND DATE. Would solve the problem anyway.

Comment: This _may_ eliminate deadlocks:  Instead of `OR`, use `IN (4, 5)` and be sure to sort the values in the list.

Comment: Would it work to do `BEGIN; SELECT ... IN (4,5) FOR UPDATE; UPDATE ... 4+5-threadid ... IN(4,5); COMMIT;` ?

Comment: No matter what you can't single step swap because there's a unique constraint on TableID + Date. When doing it this way it will run into problems with that.

Comment: An altarnative update is to use a case expression: `update tables set tableid = case when tableid = 4 then 5 else 4 end where tableid between 4 and 5 and ...`